# Solving a problem using logical operators in C programming language

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-or

```
#include <stdio.h>


void main()
{
 int a = 11, b = 5;
 if(a == 7 || 10){
     printf("True");
 }
 else
 printf("False");
}
```

This is my problem, i saw it in a question and was asked what the output would be.
i put false but the answer was true, im trying to understand why because a is not equal to any of them and the condition for it to be true is that a be equal to at least one of them

Comment: `a == 7 || 10` => `a == 7 || a == 10`. This is not English, this is C.

Comment: `void main()` -> `int main(void)`

Comment: The key thing to note is that `==` has higher precedence than logical `||` so is executed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
if (a == 7 || 10)
```

Does *not* test if `a` is equal to either 7 or 10.

The `==` operator will evaluate to 1 if both operands are equal, and 0 otherwise.  The `||` operator will evaluate to 1 if at least one operand is non-zero, and 0 otherwise.

Also, the equality operator has higher precedence than the logical OR operator.  So the above parses as:

```
if ((a == 7) || 10)
```

So the expression will be true if either `a==7` evaluates to non-zero or `10` evaluates to non-zero.  The latter is true so the condition is true.

Answer (score 3):

The expression in the if statement

```
if(a == 7 || 10){
```

is equivalent to

```
if( ( a == 7 ) || ( 10 ) ){
```

As `10` is not equal to `0` then the second operand of the logical OR operator `||` always evaluates to the logical true. So the whole expression used in the if statement has a result of the logical true.

In fact as `a` is not equal to `7` (due to its initialization) then the above if statement is equivalent to

```
if( 10 ){
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a logical error. The way you type it you don't check whether a == 7 OR a == 10 (as you wish), rather you check only if a == 7 and second condition if (10) is always true.

The fix is pretty simple actually:

```
void main()
{
 int a = 11, b = 5;
 if(a == (7 || 10)){
     printf("True");
 }
 else
 printf("False");
}
```